# On Windows 7, how do I share files on one computer, under multiple hostnames? "System error 86"

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares

For software testing, I have one machine that will attempt to access network shares under a certain hostname.

I want to host all these shares on the one machine, and not access the network - so I disconnect it from the network completely.

In my hosts file, I created an entry `127.0.0.1 somealias`, so now I can ping `somealias`.

Now, Windows Explorer (and `net use`) act like they are willing to access `\\somealias\share` (and are able to access `\\localhost\share`) but suddenly ask for username and password. No matter how I configure my sharing, my usernames, my passwords, and my share permissions, the error is along these lines: `incorrect username or password`

Using `net use`, I get more information: `System error 86`

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to tell LanmanServer that you have an alternative hostname using `regedit`:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters
```

1. Add a new *String Value* called `OptionalNames` and give it the new `somealias` value.
2. Reboot the computer (or maybe restart service *Server*)

After two days of searching, I correctly deduced that the problem is not with the sharing settings, users, or name resolving. It is with LanmanServer (the *Server* service).

A successful connection is made to the local host, when connecting to `somealias`. After that however, during authentication, the service doesn't recognize the hostname you are connecting to.